# Getting TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str when running this code

Tags: python, api, typeerror

```
import requests
class food:
    meal = requests.get('https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php')
    def __init__(self,init_meals):
     self.meals = init_meals
    def get(self):     
     meal = requests.get('https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s='+self.meals)
     json_meal = meal.json()
     meal_time = (json_meal['meals'][0]['strMeal'])
     return (meal_time)
    def recipe(self):
     meal = requests.get('https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s='+self.meals)
     json_meal = meal.json()
     recipes = int(json_meal['meals']['0']['strInstructions'])
     return (recipe_time)
```

When running this code I get:
File "/import/linux/home1/jgarc111/final-exam-fall20-jgarc111/food.py", line 14, in recipe
recipes = int(json_meal['meals']['0']['strInstructions'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Take the quotes off from around that `0`.  You're turning it from an int into a str.

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
 recipes = int(json_meal['meals']['0']['strInstructions'])
```

Try:

```
  recipes = int(json_meal['meals'][0]['strInstructions'])
```

json_meal['meals'] is a list and not a dictionary.